# Grails UserType mapping with Gorm 6.1

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm having a problem with a mapping in Grails 3.3. I've created a custom type "PriceType" which uses two columns, amount and currency. I have a property of this type in a domain class and I get a "Cannot treat multi-column property as a single-column property" when I start up the application.

This is the mapping in the domain class:

```
@Entity
class PaymentClientsInformation {
    ...
    Price amount
    ...

    static constraints = {
        ...
        amount nullable: true
        ...
    }

    static mapping = {
        amount type: PriceType, {
            column name: 'PRICE_AMOUNT'
            column name: 'PRICE_CURRENCY'
        }
    }
}
```

and the sqlTypes of the type:

```
int[] sqlTypes() {
    [BigDecimalType.INSTANCE.sqlType(), StringType.INSTANCE.sqlType()]
}
```

Has anyone faced this problem? (edited)

Comment: Why you didn;t stick with CoC pattern of grails?

Comment: There are often cases like this where the stock functionality of Grails isn't sufficient and customization like this is needed

Comment: I'm migrationg this from Grails 2.5.6 and it was working fine, it would be hard to stick the CoC pattern.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more codes of your domain?